# Check for special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to prevent users inputing special characters ()&<>[]{}%   in the many input and text areas of our website. Which is the best way ? Users use IE8, Firefox and Chrome. The name and id in the input and textarea is dynamic. I have no control over it.

So basically, I just want a function and use the onclick event to call it. I thought :input selector would do the work. Thanks.

Please take a look at [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/AR323/3/)

```
function spCheck () 
{var str = $('textarea').val();
if(/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/.test(str) == false) {
alert('You have entered illegal characterss. Please remove them and try again.');
}}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? Your code seems to function as expected.

Comment: Sorry, if I am not clear. When a user enters illegal characters into the textarea or input box, the alert needs to pop up. I have no control of adding classes or ids. My JS Fiddle, works only on the first text area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add class  `notSpecilChar` to elements you want to check and on `blur` alert or `keyup` event.

```
$('.notSpecilChar').blur(function () {
    if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/.test(this.value) === false) {
        alert('You have entered illegal characterss. Please remove them and try again.');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi! Tushar, Thanks for the reply, but I cannot add any class as well, the textarea and input is generated automatically. On the client side there are buttons to input textarea, buttons, input fields..etc...

Comment: @19eggs you have given class  `someclass` to all textarea and textbox which is common class you can use the class.

Comment: Like I said before, I have no control of adding classes and ids as they are created dynamically.